# Code first EF 6 auto generated relation table with additional column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am trying to create new table with relation many to many in the code first.
I have got two tables: Users and Projects. Now, i want to have relation many to many for this two tables. So i do following:

```
    public class Project
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PositionCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, Guid> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class RecruitmentDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, MyRole, Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProject> UserProjects { get;set; }

    public RecruitmentDbContext()
        : base("RecruitmentDB")
    {
    }}
```

I saw on this [page](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) that this is enough to create new table with relation many to many. This is true, because everything works properly. But i want to add new column to this auto generated table, with name "ApplicationStatus". I need this column, because i need to know, if for current user, current project has current status :)

So summarizing:
I want to have got a table with relation many to many and with additional column named ApplicationStatus. Is it possible to get this on auto generated table, or maybe i should create it by hand somehow?

Comment: Once you add additional columns to a many-to-many table it ceases to be a many-to-many.  You need to map it one-many and many-one with a new entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. This should help.

[Entity Framework : Customized Join Table in a Many to Many Relationship](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2014/11/entity-framework-customized-join-table.html)

Comment: You've done what i explained in my comment.  in your link, you've created a new entity and made it a one to many from each side of the relationship.  it's no longer a many to many between the original entities.